# Javascript/jquery Images slideshow does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create an easy slideshow but It is not that easy at all :(.

I have few problems to make it work.

Here is my code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/WUE9g/1/

PS: I would much appreciate any kind of help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had an unclosed function call in your code, check now: http://jsfiddle.net/WUE9g/3/

Use firebug, it has an error console that tells you what's going on.

Comment: It works now. Thanks! Also, do you know a good way to add two buttons(right - left) to slide content? Thanks again.

Comment: @Martin, fix the `<ul>` css to make it appear, and make an `onclick="rotatePics(-1)"` and `onclick="rotatePics(1)`" on the left/right buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your parenthesis are not matching. Use

```
$(function() {
    rotatePics(1);
});
```

instead of

```
$(function() {
    rotatePics(1);
}
```

Since `$` is a shortcut to the `jQuery` function, you need to use it like any other function (e.g. `rotatePics()`).